# Downloading a multiple copies of a torrent

Tags: bittorrent

I am in a situation where i need to download a torrent more than once simultaneously. 
Normally a user downloads a torrent file and downloads "one copy" of the files from seeds and peers and uploads it

I need to download the same file many times parallely (yes a very weird request i know) and i dont care about waste of internet bandwidth or disk space... is it possible??... any way to modify a torrent software to do this?

Comment: It certainly should be possible.  I would start by modifying how a file is placed into the download queue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most clients I'm aware of key their list of torrents that are loaded/downloading by their info-hash. The info-hash is often used as a unique identifier within the client as well, which might make it hard to modify a client to support downloading the same torrent in parallel.

You could just run multiple processes, one for each copy of the torrent you want to download. With uTorrent you can pass in `/RECOVER` to circumvent the single-instance check for instance. I would imagine most clients have similar features. If not, you could try to leverage the OS to sandbox the client instances from each other, with a jail for instance.

However, that seems like a very straight forward and simple solution. The fact that you're asking seems to imply that you might have some other expectations on downloading the same torrent in parallel. Like, do you want them to share data between each other? (i.e. the old seeding-a-torrent-on-multiple-private-trackers problem).

Depending on what you want the "torrent software" to do, you could write a thin wrapper around [libtorrent](http://libtorrent.org) and run one session per instance of the torrent you want to download.

Answer (score 1):

I have not used them, but you should look in to a command line torrent client and simply launch multiple instances for the same torrent. You may need to point to different output directories if the client wont add some random suffix to the files to prevent duplicate file names, but that should be a minor hurdle.

Your options for a command line torrent clients are going to vary depending on your operating system, but you should be able to find something. I know bit-torrent and rtorrent have command line clients for linux.